# `Compiz` profile settings export and import using command line

Tags: command-line, compiz, settings

How can i export and import `Compiz` current profile settings using Command line.
I'm using ubuntu 12.10. Or can i get a script for doing export and import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of a command line utility, but you can easily do this with a script in Python and `python-compizconfig` package. Here you go:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os
import compizconfig

#The last input on the command line will be the path to save the file to.
savefile=sys.argv[-1]

context=compizconfig.Context()
#Change keyword if you want to skip saving entries that are default
context.Export(os.path.abspath(savefile),skipDefaults=False)
```

To import settings, you could just change the last line to `context.Import(os.path.abspath(savefile))`

Now to run, just save and `chmod +x scriptname.py` and run `./scriptname.py FILE` or run with `python scriptname.py FILE` if you don't `chmod`.

WARNING- I have only tested a bit and basic functionality works, but I guarantee nothing. The script can be made much more robust and functional.

Comment: Thank you very much +Ian B. This is what I exactly needed...Thanks

Comment: When running from the crontab it only exports default values for everyting... any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Small update I wanted to add to importing that I found.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#http://askubuntu.com/questions/244333/compiz-profile-settings-export-and-import-using-command-line
import sys
import compizconfig

#The last input on the command line will be the path to save the file to.
savefile=sys.argv[-1]

context=compizconfig.Context()

#saveFile is the name of the file. True specifies whether or not to overwrite current settings.
context.Import(savefile, True)
```

I was having an issue on import where it didn't seem to be overwriting the default values.  Appending True to the end of the Import statement seems to have fixed that.